# Can we give multiple things in the findAll

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have an Employee domain that has the Professional_id in it. Professional domain has a field called level in it. Now I want to extract all the Employee that are on same level. How can I write the query?

I want something like

```
def emp = Employee.findAllByProfessional_id(Professional.findAllByLevel(5))
```

Employee domain-:

```
class Employee {
    String username
    String password
    String reg_no
    String designation
    String personal_id
    String professional_id
    static constraints = {
        username(unique:true)
        password(password:true)
    }
}
```

Professional domain -:

```
class Professional {
    int level
    String bank_account_no
    String qualification
    String salary
    String department
    String performance
    String basic_pay
    String fax_no
    String employee_awards
    String job_duration
    String work_shift

    static constraints = {
        bank_account_no(unique:true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Professional.findAllByLevel(5)** will return a list of Professional objects, but **Employee.findAllByProfessional_id()** is waiting a list of Strings, since the attribute professional_id is a String in your Employee class. Because of that what you're trying to do will not work.

Try to do that:

```
def emp = Employee.findAllByProfessional_id(Professional.findAllByLevel(5).id.toString())
```

Anyway, it looks like your domain is not correctly defined. You don't need to specify a professional_id field as you're doing in Employee class. You should specify an association using belongsTo, hasMany, hasOne.